# How to change a select form by buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a select form:

```
<select>
    <option value ="one">Label 1</option>
    <option value ="two">Label 2</option>
    <option value ="three">Label 3</option>
</select>
```

but I also have some buttons that call the same functions as the select form would

```
<button class="one">Label 1</button>
<button class="two">Label 2</button>
<button class="three">Label 3</button>
```

So if I select one of these buttons how could I change the option that shows up in the select form (by that I mean the text that's in the form before you open it up) ?

so if you `$("button.three").click();` "Label 3" would show up in the select form

I'm not sure what the function is to change the `<select>`'s label. I've tried these but they don't work:

```
$("select").select().val("three");
$("select").find([value="three"]).select();
$("select").selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var selectedClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $("option[value="+ selectedClass + "]").attr("selected", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("select").val("three");`

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the simplest solution:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $('select').val($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/05bbztLx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently others beat me to the answer while I was writing a response, but eh... here's a non-jQuery solution. ;)

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
var mySelectOptions = mySelect.getElementsByTagName('option');

for (var i = 0, length = buttons.length; i < length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.onclick = function(event) {
        var text = event.target.innerText;

        for (var x = 0, length = mySelectOptions.length; x < length; x++) {
            var option = mySelectOptions[x];

            if (option.innerText === text) {
                mySelect.selectedIndex = x;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/x1chabLa/